# low latency audio streaming

Tags: networking, sound, pulseaudio, kde

Problems:
Cant find any good way to stream audio with low latency to a windows computer. I'm thinking of something like what voice meeter has where you can stream audio using what they call vban but in linux.

Hopes:
That i will find a solution with under 50ms of latency but anything under 500ms would work.

Possible Solutions:
Using pulse audio to stream a rtp stream and recieving it on my laptop.

using darkice and icecast. This is rather flawed as its ment to have lots of latency

I'd be very greatful if someone knew what i should be doing here to make this work better.

Comment: Have you tried using a low-latency kernel? Ubuntu Studio uses a lowlatency kernel by default

Comment: does that work over a network?

Comment: I suppose the lowlatency kernel will win you a couple of milliseconds, but yeah I don't think that the kernel latency is the real problem here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know the question is quite old, but you may still like to know that the vban for linux project has gone 1 step forward recently and now provides both a receptor and an emitter: https://github.com/quiniouben/vban.
Together with VoiceMeeter on the windows side, or VBAN Receptor on Android or iOS device, you should achieve a quite fast audio over ip between Linux, Windows, Android and iOS devices. 
Note: latency of the linux vban_emitter is not yet tuneable but is using a not too big buffer size (<= 25ms depending on the configuration).

Comment: I'll look at this in the next few days. I have used this project in the past to get low latency audio from my windows to my linux. I'm glad it now works the other way around. outa curriousity how would i send audio and recieve from my android device. Have you written that one as well or no?

Comment: I only took care of the open source project in github. For now, it only exists receptors for iOS and Android, including a free "lite" version. Streaming from windows to Android / iOS should work like you used to do with linux vban_receptor, with a nice GUI on your mobile device. Using vban_emiiter to sending from linux is now pretty similar to the use of vban_receptor.

Comment: Thanks. I'll have to check this all out. I'll be checking probly tomorrow as i have more time then to mess around with it. Thanks for this it looks like it will work like I want. Hopefully just as good as the windows version with maybe a little more latency. Thanks

Comment: Just wanted to let you know that I love this. I've used it the past few days and it works amazingly well for this. ffmpeg with rtp streaming works fairly well too dont get me wrong but this just has less latency which is really nice